# Gstreamer RTSP Server not working (SDP contains no streams)

Tags: python, server, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

Here is my code for GstRtspServer that should just stream mp4 file for now:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GstRtspServer

GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)


class RTSP_Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = GstRtspServer.RTSPServer.new()
        self.address = '192.168.1.15'
        self.port = '8554'
        self.launch_description = '( playbin uri=file:///E://...sample_video.mp4 )'

        self.server.set_address(self.address)
        self.server.set_service(self.port)
        self.server.connect("client-connected",self.client_connected) 
        self.factory = GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory.new()
        self.factory.set_launch(self.launch_description)
        self.factory.set_shared(True)
        self.factory.set_transport_mode(GstRtspServer.RTSPTransportMode.PLAY)
        self.mount_points = self.server.get_mount_points()
        self.mount_points.add_factory('/video', self.factory)

        self.server.attach(None)  
        print('Stream ready')
        GObject.MainLoop().run()

    def client_connected(self, arg1, arg2):
        print('Client connected')


server = RTSP_Server()
```

I run it, get 'Stream ready' and then type in command line:

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin>gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.15:8554/video latency=0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

And receive this:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.1.15:8554/video
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Could not get/set settings from/on resource.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(6845): gst_rtspsrc_setup_streams (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSP
Src:rtspsrc0:
SDP contains no streams
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin>
```

Also I receive 'Client connected' in Python and first frame of the video opens and then closes after a moment.

- Gst.parse_launch('playbin uri=file:///E://...sample_video.mp4') works OK  - (with full address)
- VLC says that it is impossible to open rtsp://192.168.1.15:8554/video
- I've tried launching it on another computer in local network
- With 127.0.0.1 as well
- And receive stream without latency=0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink

What's the problem? I am looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your server is listening on:

> self.port = '554'

while You are trying to play port 8554:

> VLC says that it is impossible to open rtsp://192.168.1.15:8554/video

Comment: I was trying different ports, so it is a misprint. On another forum I received an answer that playbin doesn't fit RTSP server and also I should include name=payX in pipeline. Now I am playing to make it works on Raspberry Pi..

Comment: Vassiliev - Could you provide a link to the answer you referred to on another forum? 
 I'm having the same problem on a RPi.  Thanks